# AngularJs does not display list populated from a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular by working through a tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM), but I cannot get the following example work. The example shows how to use routes using a View1.html which should display a list of customers (simple name, city object) and possibility to add, filter customers.

When I tried the sample, the customers list wouldn't get displayed -- I can just see the bullet points and all the labels, texts etc., but no list of name - city.
When I replace the list in View1.html with a hardcoded list, it shows correctly.

What could be wrong here?

**Code**

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="angularTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

*View1.html*

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
Name:
<br/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name"/>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:city"></li>
</ul>
<br/>
Customer name<br/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
<br/>
Customer city<br/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>
<br/>
<button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer</button>

<br/>

<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
```

*View2.html*

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 2</h2>
Name:
<br/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="city"/>
<br/>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:city"></li>
</ul>
```

*angularTest.js*

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);


app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/',
    {
        controller: 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/View1.html'
    })
    .when('/view2',
    {
        controller: 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/View2.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

app.controller('SimpleController',
function SimpleController($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        {name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York'},
        {name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'San Fransisco'},
        {name: 'Joe Smith', city: 'Washington'}
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
        $scope.customers.push(
            {
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city
            }
        );
    };
}
);
```

Comment: Your li tag does not contain any markup for displaying name and city. Try adding in it something like this: <span>{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</span>

Comment: thanks to those who answered. Forgot the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your li element You Need to put

```
<li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:city">{{cust.name}} ({{cust.city}})</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print something inside li tag to shown up something on view {{ }} provides you that privilege:-

```
<li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:city">{{cust.name}} ({{cust.city}})</li>
```